# Scrollview inside fragment not scrolling at all

Tags: android, scrollview

I am using three fragments in one activity with tablayout. In fragment I have 12 edittext so I put them into the scrollview.But scrolling is not working and I can see only few edittexts.

fragment.xml

```
 <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:background="#fffbfbfb"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <TableLayout

            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="0"
            android:background="#fffbfbfb">
     ........
</scrollview>
```

activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: HI , Copy all views in fragment.xml .

Comment: share your fragment.xml full code

Comment: in your question you said tab layout and in code you are using table layout??

Comment: @vivek Mishra  I mean to switch between fragments I used tab layout in activity.xml

Comment: add this line to your scroll view  android:fillViewport="true"

Comment: so add scrollview in your activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I did one thing in fragment.java file:

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                scrollView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Now scrollview is working fine but viewpager has stopped working I mean I am not able to change fragment by horizontally touch as it was working before putting above method in fragment.java

Answer (score 4):

If you are using scrollview inside coordinator layout, instead of using default scrollview, try using [NestedScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

Answer (score 1):

**try this in your code and make sure Scroll view have single child**

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:isScrollContainer="false"

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
```

**if still not work then wrap table layout in Linear Layout**