# Scollview not scrolling inside viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have searched and tried lots of things but nothing is working for me. I have one parent Activity as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".screens.CompleteProfileActivity"
android:id="@+id/parent">

<mypackage.CustomSwipableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_8"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/prevclick"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/left_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_prev_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/previous"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_16" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nextclick"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_16" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/finishclick"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_finish_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@string/finish"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_16" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And I have one Fragment inside viewpager like as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_16"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_16">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_16">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ques1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:text="Date of Birth"
                android:textColor="@color/textDark"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/year"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorAccent"
                    android:hint="@string/year"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="4"
                    android:textColor="@color/textDark"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_18" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" / "
                    android:textColor="@color/textDark"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_32" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/month"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorAccent"
                    android:hint="@string/month"
                    android:inputType="text|number"
                    android:maxLength="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/textDark"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_18" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=" / "
                    android:textColor="@color/textDark"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_32" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/day"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="?attr/colorAccent"
                    android:hint="@string/day"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2"
                    android:textColor="@color/textDark"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_18" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ques2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:text="@string/doing_job_for"
                android:textColor="@color/textDark"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/ques1RG"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/you_need_money"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/everyone_has_to_do_job"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/parent_want_good_life"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/you_want_to_build_career"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/checkboxll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ques3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:text="@string/who_all_in_family"
                android:textColor="@color/textDark"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_20" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/my_father"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/my_mother"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/my_bro_sis"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/only_me"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="@string/none"
                android:textColor="@color/light_grey" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the list what I have tried : 
 1. putting my activity inside CoordinatorLayout+appbar+toolbar and using NestedScrollView in fragment.
 2. [ScrollView inside ViewPager, scrolls to middle automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16182331/3758972)
 3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37247305/3758972
 4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35448706/3758972
and much more. But nothing seems to work. Please help!!